# Boost ptr_list accessing subclass methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost

To start out, I am just returning to c++ from a 20 or so year absence.  I am just working to figure out some stuff.  I want to create a class hierarchy and instantiate subclasses of a base class into a list and iterate on the list and get the subclass back in the iterator or find a way to accomplish this.

```
namespace FooBar {

class ace {
public: ace::ace(){};
public: virtual int ace::getValue(){ return 1; };
};

class base : public ace {
public: base::base(){};

**// Added method for casting
public: base::base(ace){};**

public: int base::getValue(){ return 2; };
};

class face : public ace {
public: face::face(){};

**// Added method for casting
public: face::face(ace){};**

public: int face::getValue(){ return 3; };
};
}
```

I create instances of the appropriate sub class to insert on the list.  I can't sort out how to get the sub class back from the iterator.  I've tried adding an identifier so I would know which class it was, but I can't work out how to cast the iterator.

```
int main() {
using namespace FooBar;

boost::ptr_list<ace> theList;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    ace* foo;
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        foo = new base();
    else
        foo = new face();
    theList.push_back(foo);
}

for (boost::ptr_list<ace>::iterator iter = theList.begin(); iter != theList.end(); iter++){
    std::cout << (*iter).getValue() << ", ";

    // cast to sub class; Is it of type base
    if (typeid(base) == typeid(*iter)){
       base bar = static_cast<base>(*iter);
     }
     else {typeid(face) == typeid(*iter)){
        face bar = static_cast<face>(*iter);
     }
}
}
```

the output is 1, 1, ...

Both casts above fail with no suitable user-defined conversion from ace to base/face exists;

So, I created a constructor for both base and face as shown in added comment;
and the error I now get is

ace::ace(const ace &) cannot be references it is a deleted function.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't sort out how to get the sub class back from the iterator

You can't, the way you currently have it set up. C++ has no run time type information (rtti) except for classes which are polymorphic (classes which have at least one virtual function).

You can make `getValue` virtual (just write `virtual` before it), and not need to get a pointer to the derived class from a pointer to the base class. That would be the idiomatic solution here.

If you actually had a case you needed to get a derived type from a base type pointer (and the class had a virtual function) you can either use `dynamic_cast` or a combination of `typeid` and `static_cast` to figure out what the derived type is.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that yesterday at work and I was unable to add the instance to the list because it was virtual.  I will have to see what is different between this reduced version and the solution I am working on.

Comment: I actually had two virtual member functions and one was pure virtual so I made both virtual and I got past that point.  I still can't work out how to perform the cast.  I have edited the question to be more explicit about what the issue is.